# Python error decoding a base64 string of a hazmart Cipher

Tags: python, encryption

I have a function that encodes an encrypted string (using hazmat Cipher) in base64 representation, but when I try to decrypt it later using a different function I am getting an error:

```
web_1  |   File "/code/cart/models.py", line 58, in decrypt_hash_id
web_1  |     int_id = int(padded_id.decode('utf-8').lstrip(' '))
web_1  | UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

My encryption function is:

```
from django.conf import settings
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode, urlsafe_b64decode
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

def url_safe_encrypted_id(self):
    backend = default_backend()
    key = settings.URL_ENCRYPTION_KEY
    iv = settings.URL_ENCRYPTION_IV
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    ct = encryptor.update(str(self.id).rjust(16).encode()) + encryptor.finalize()
    return urlsafe_b64encode(ct)
```

However when I try to decrypt this base64 string I am sometimes getting an error. My method for decrypting is:

```
def decrypt_hash_id(hash):
    # Decode order_id
    backend = default_backend()
    key = settings.URL_ENCRYPTION_KEY
    iv = settings.URL_ENCRYPTION_IV
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    padded_id = decryptor.update(urlsafe_b64decode((hash + '===').encode())) + decryptor.finalize()
    int_id = int(padded_id.decode().lstrip(' '))
    
    return int_id
```

Can anyone help to see where the problem might lie? Probably 99% of the time it's working correctly, but occasionally I will get the error shown above.

Comment: Please, add the import modules statements, so I can examine your code.

Comment: @Nour-AllahHussein I updated my code to show the import statements that are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem you have. It is in the line:

```
 padded_id = decryptor.update(urlsafe_b64decode((hash + '===').encode())) + decryptor.finalize()
```

just modify it to:

```
padded_id = decryptor.update(urlsafe_b64decode(hash.decode())) + decryptor.finalize()
```

Here is a full example code, but with some modification to run:

```
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode, urlsafe_b64decode
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

class settings:
    URL_ENCRYPTION_KEY=b'1234567890123456'
    URL_ENCRYPTION_IV=b'1234567890123456'

def url_safe_encrypted_id(text):
    backend = default_backend()
    key = settings.URL_ENCRYPTION_KEY
    iv = settings.URL_ENCRYPTION_IV
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    ct = encryptor.update(text.rjust(16).encode()) + encryptor.finalize()
    return urlsafe_b64encode(ct)


def decrypt_hash_id(hash):
    # Decode order_id
    backend = default_backend()
    key = settings.URL_ENCRYPTION_KEY
    iv = settings.URL_ENCRYPTION_IV
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    padded_id = decryptor.update(urlsafe_b64decode(hash.decode())) + decryptor.finalize()
    int_id = int(padded_id.decode().lstrip(' '))

    return int_id

text='10'
enc=url_safe_encrypted_id(text)
dec=decrypt_hash_id(enc)
print(text)
print(enc)
print(dec)
# output:
# 10
# b'l5DfiYydiPUCzGK7eLXOFQ=='
# 10
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import base64 

def encrypt():
    string = "Hello world this is a sample string"
    str_bytes = sample_string.encode("ascii")

    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(str_bytes) 
    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")
    print(f"Encoded string: {base64_string}") 

def decrypt():
    base64_string =" R2Vla3NGb3JHZWVrcyBpcyB0aGUgYmVzdA =="
    base64_bytes = base64_string.encode("ascii")
    sample_string_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_bytes) 
    sample_string = sample_string_bytes.decode("ascii")

    print(f"Decoded string: {sample_string}")
```

Comment: Your code is good for a safe URL, but it does not make cryptography.